# listview - my new inserted data is replacing earlier data

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am beginner android developer and this is my first project. I have a listview on EntryTO.java to show data order from selected listview on ViewData.java. i use button to show ViewData,java. this is the code when i choose selected item from ViewData.java

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
          lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, final long id) {
          final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ViewData.this);
          dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
          dialog.setTitle("Masukkan Qty");
          dialog.show();
          final product b = (product) getListAdapter().getItem(pos);
          edtqty = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtqty);
          buttonok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonok);
          buttonok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
              switchToEdit(b.getId());
              dialog.dismiss();
                   };
             });
          }
      });
  }
  public void switchToEdit(long id){
      product b = dataSource.getproduct(id);
      Intent i = new Intent(this, EntryTO.class);
      Bundle bun = new Bundle();

      bun.putLong("id", b.getId());
      bun.putString("brand", b.getbrand());
      bun.putString("qty",edtqty.getText().toString());
      i.putExtras(bun);
      finale();
      startActivity(i);
  }
```

And this is the code when i try to display on EntryTO.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.entry_to);
      dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
      dataSource.open();
      mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
      Bundle bun = null;
      try{
          bun = EntryTO.this.getIntent().getExtras();
          id = bun.getLong("id");
          brand = bun.getString("brand");
          qty = bun.getString("qty");
          map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
          if(map1.isEmpty()){
             map1.put("one", brand);
             map1.put("two", qty); 
             mylist.add(map1); 
          }else{
              int j=mylist.lastIndexOf(map1);
              map1.put("one", brand);
              map1.put("two", qty); 
              mylist.add(j,map1); 
          }
          try {
              adapter = new SimpleAdapter(EntryTO.this, mylist, R.layout.item_to,
                        new String[] {"one", "two" },
                        new int[] {R.id.edtbrandto, R.id.edtqtyto });
              setListAdapter(adapter);
          }catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(EntryTO.this, "Ada Error Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
      }catch(NullPointerException e){}}
```

I try to use loop before. When I insert first order there's no problem. But when I try to insert second order, the second replaced the first order. It caused when i click button that shown ViewData.java, index of arraylist become 0 again. Now I try to check index of arraylist(mylist) with if function. If mylist.isEmpty insert data order, but when mylist is not empty get the index of latest data order and insert new data after that. The problem is, second data still replaced first data. How do i fix them?

Comment: you may check the id of the newly inserted data

Comment: how do i check the id

Comment: You are checking `if(map1.isEmpty())` which is always true

Comment: mylist.add(j,map1); 
in this j is the last index you have to increment it by 1 before adding like  mylist.add((j+1),map1);

Comment: @And.Dev there is no change :(

Comment: @ling.s do you have any sugest? i try to detect content on arraylist. i have tried using mylist.isEmpty, mylist.content(map1),etc. there is no change

Comment: @WardaLyn instead of `if(map1.isEmpty())` check mylist size > 0. can you edit your question with full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that answer from @ling.s was right. but it need some finishing touched. i try to make Globals.java. this is the code

```
public class Globals {
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
```

}

on EntryTO.java we just call mylist from Globals.java

```
if (Globals.mylist == null)
          Globals.mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
      Bundle bun = null;
      try{
          bun = EntryTO.this.getIntent().getExtras();
          id = bun.getLong("id");
          brand = bun.getString("brand");
          qty = bun.getString("qty");
          map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
          if (Globals.mylist.size() == 0) {
              map1.put("one", brand);
              map1.put("two", qty); 
              Globals.mylist.add(map1);
          }else {
              int j=Globals.mylist.size();
              map1.put("one", brand);
              map1.put("two", qty); 
              Globals.mylist.add(j,map1);
          }
          try {
              adapter = new SimpleAdapter(EntryTO.this, Globals.mylist, R.layout.item_to,
                        new String[] {"one", "two" },
                        new int[] {R.id.edtbrandto, R.id.edtqtyto });
              setListAdapter(adapter);
          }catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(EntryTO.this, "Ada Error Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
      }catch(NullPointerException e){}
```

its work.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the approach you chose means you would need to store in your class the content you're passing to the `ArrayAdapter` implementation as the **third** parameter (i.e., the `ArrayList` of initial elements).

This way, if you need to add a new element, you just have to add it to that `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

For instance:

```
ArrayList<String> my_items = new ArrayList<String>();
my_items.add("one");
my_items.add("two");

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(EntryTO.this, mylist, R.layout.item_to, my_items);
```

And if you want to add an item, just do:

```
my_items.add("three");
adapter.dataSetChanged();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it cant solve the problem. the count of my_item might have depended from how much i choose order from another listview on another activity

Comment: I don't get what is the problem. But if you choose that approach, that's the way of procceeding.

Comment: sometime we've to choose 10 order,maybe less than 3, we cant always change the code before we choose order. that is teh problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `if(map1.isEmpty())` which is always true. 
Use

```
if(mylist.size() == 0)
```

Instead of

```
if(map1.isEmpty())
```

and, to find out the next element going to be inserted, get the size which adds an item to the last position.

```
int j=mylist.size();
```